# Maven - exec-maven-plugin - CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin, pscp

I am using this code to upload a `JAR` file to a Server right after the `Install` phase:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>server-deployment</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>D:\my-folder\pscp.exe -r -i D:\my-folder-conf\user.ppk D:\my-folder-jar\file-1.1.0.jar ubuntu@X.XX.XX.XXX:/usr/local/folder1/jar/file-1.1.0.jar</executable>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The command:

```
D:\my-folder\pscp.exe -r -i D:\my-folder-conf\user.ppk D:\my-folder-jar\file-1.1.0.jar ubuntu@X.XX.XX.XXX:/usr/local/folder1/jar/file-1.1.0.jar
```

Works from `Windows Console` normally and the file is uploaded, but when I execute the very same command with the `exec-maven-plugin`, it fails with the message: `CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. If I am providing full paths and extensions to all files, how does this happen? Is there any solution for this=

**Solution:**

I ended up using the approach of @xerx593, thanks for your help, here bellow is the final solution:

```
<configuration>
  <executable>D:\my-folder\pscp.exe</executable>
  <arguments>
    <argument>-r</argument>        
    <argument>-i</argument>      
    <argument>D:\my-folder-conf\user.ppk</argument>       
    <argument>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument> 
    <argument>ubuntu@X.XX.XX.XXX:/usr/local/folder1/jar/${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>  
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Simply the wrong tool for it.. Use something else like Ansible / CI/CD solution but don't try to abuse Maven for that...Already having absolute paths in it makes it impossible to use for others or on a CI solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```xml
    <configuration>
      <executable>D:\my-folder\pscp.exe</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-r</argument>        
        <argument>-i</argument>      
        <argument>D:\my-folder-conf\user.ppk</argument>       
        <argument>D:\my-folder-jar\file-1.1.0.jar</argument> 
        <argument>ubuntu@X.XX.XX.XXX:/usr/local/folder1/jar/file-1.1.0.jar</argument>  
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
```

...as [documented](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) (& [shown](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)) instead.